# Microsoft Outlook - Is it possible to differentiate incoming mails by author and automatically put into specific personal folders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

Just wondering if this is possible.

For example, if I were receiving a lot of emails from one group, could I set a list of folks from the group so that Microsoft Outlook knows to put all those emails from them to a specific personal folder?  Otherwise, I would have to manually go through it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a filter.

Select **Tools > Rules Wizard...** This will guide you through the process which is basically (working from memory):

1. Select "New..."
2. Select "Check messages when the arrive".
3. Select option that allows you to specify the senders. This might have a different format depending on what version of Outlook you are using. Add the people you want.
4. Select "Move to specified folder" and pick the folder where you want them to move to.

And that should be it.

You can run the rule straight away to test it (safe as long as it doesn't permanently delete the mail!). This will then run while Outlook is running.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on a message you wish to move and click "Rule" then "Create Rule" then you can choose the "from (that email address)" then click "Move the item to folder" you can then click the "Select Folder" button to pick the folder you have already created and hit "OK". now every incoming email from that address will be moved to that folder. You can setup a rule for each email you wish to. I hope this helped.